# Isn't possible to call Delegate Methods programmatically?

Tags: xcode, delegates, core-plot

I would like to ask isn't possible to call Delegate Methods programmatically?
I would like to call the Axis Delegate Methods in core plot library manually to update my axis after some autoscale.

```
-(BOOL)axis:(CPTAxis *)axis shouldUpdateAxisLabelsAtLocations:(NSSet *)locations
```

I don't want to create another method to call since it do the same job with the axis delegate.  How can I call the delegate manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can all it just like any other method, there is nothing "special" about delegate methods.

```
[self axis:axis shouldUpdateAxisLabelsAtLocations:locations];
```

assuming you have variables `axis` and `locations` that contain the information you want to pass.